# R program question: What code I have to use to calculate 3 columns into one column?

Tags: r, windows

In example we have:

```
   treetype Leaves roots
1.   1        670    25
2.   4        330    55
3.   8        880    55
4.   3        770    25
```

Wanted solution:

```
   New value
1. 696   (1+670+25)
2. 389   (4+330+55)
3. and so on
```

And second question:
if value doesn't meet required value, i.e. 550 then calculate new value using only leaves.
-> 2. row in wanted solution should be 330.

any tips?

Answer (score 2):

This is a task which is suitable for the dplyr package, which is part of tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(treetype = c(1,4,8,3),
                   Leaves = c(670, 330, 880, 770),
                   roots  = c(25,55,55,25))

limit <- 550

data <- data %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(New_value = ifelse(treetype+Leaves+roots < limit, Leaves, treetype+Leaves+roots))
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, here is a solution using base R (no extra packages).

```
data <- data.frame(treetype = c(1,4,8,3),
                   Leaves = c(670, 330, 880, 770),
                   roots  = c(25,55,55,25))

limit <- 550

data$limit_test <- data$treetype + data$Leaves + data$roots > limit
data$New_value[data$limit_test] <- (data$treetype + data$Leaves + data$roots)[data$limit_test]
data$New_value[!data$limit_test] <- (data$Leaves)[!data$limit_test]
data$limit_test <- NULL
```